# How to create this animated white picture frame effect

Tags: animation, grease-pencil

[image]

I just ain't very much familiar with 2D animation and grease pencil - How can I recreate this effect?
For the full video of this effect - the last video on this page:
https://photography.tutsplus.com/articles/bday-templates-resolve--cms-41324